# Can't pass parameter to ContentView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the next code of ContentView:

```
     <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Frame
            HeightRequest="{Binding Height}"
            WidthRequest="{Binding Width}"
            CornerRadius="{Binding Radius}"
            Margin="0"
            Padding="0">
            <Label Text="Some text" />
          </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

    public partial class CicrleView : ContentView
    {
        public int XCoord { get; set; }
        public int YCoord { get; set; }
        public int Radius { get; set; }

        private int width;
        public int Width
        {
            get
            {
                return Radius * 2;
            }
            set
            {
                this.width = value;
            }
        }

        private int height;
        public int Height
        {
            get
            {
                return Radius * 2;
            }
            set
            {
                this.height = value;
            }
        }

        public CicrleView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }        
    }
```

When I use CircleView and pass parameter "Radius" `<local:CicrleView Radius="50" />` nothing will happen (property Radius will not initialize). How can I resolve this problem and initialize Radius property in CircleView?

Comment: Seems like your problem is in BindingContext. Set it to self in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for `Radius` is set after the `CircleView` is instantiated - and because there is no property-change notification - it doesn't get propagated to inner `Frame.CornerRadius`.

In order to resolve this, either create a bindable property for `Radius`, or ensure `PropertyChanged` is invoked.

```
public int Radius
{
    get { return _radius; }
    set { _radius = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Radius)); }
}
```

Also, make sure to set the parent host view as binding source.

```
CornerRadius="{Binding Radius, Source=_parentHost}
```

and, assign `x:Name` attribute to root tag in `CircleView` XAML:

```
<ContentView .... x:Name="_parentHost" ..
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But why do we need to set x:Name="_parentHost"? Can we set this.BindingContext to this?

Comment: If you do that, you lose the ability to set an actual view-model as `BindingContext` - so for view to view bindings I usually recommend using `Source`.